# grabbing POST values with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

Forgive me for asking a seemingly obvious question, but all of my searching is turning up guides on how to create POST values with JS, not how to grab (and utilize) them.

What I want to do:

step1.php -- form `POST`ing to step2.php

step2.php -- also a form, JS grabs one particular POST value and does some work with it, then updates this new form accordingly

for reasons not worth getting into, the process needs to be a 2 step//2 page process.

The obvious solution is just to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function damn_ugly () {

        var shameful = <?php echo $_POST['desiredDatum']; ?>;
        do more stuff...
    }

</script>
```

but that seems a bit dirty to me.

Is there a better way? or is that really how I'm *supposed* to do it?

Comment: any particular reason why you cannot make the first step1.php page be dynamic and do an ajax post to step2.php, return some data that some javascript function can use? This breaks you '2step/2page process' but seems to be a better solution if you're not liking the formatting as above...

Comment: To be honest, unifying the functionality of those 2 forms into one is simply beyond my present ability, and I'm the sole coder on the site in question. I'm only just taking my first hesitant steps into adding incremental javascript enhancements to a strong PHP foundation, and am trying very hard not to bite off more than I can chew. :-)

Comment: take a look at jQuery and some of their examples... You will find that it is MUCH easier than you suspect.. one call and it sends your data (which was packed into a JS array) to your PHP form (which you already know how to use) and it then returns to a JS function whatever data you've set to output from the php form. http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var postData = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
```

You can obviously change that to include only certain fields from `$_POST` by passing a custom array to `json_encode`.

```
var desiredDatum = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['desiredDatum']); ?>;
```

There is no nicer way to do it - and using `json_encode` ensures no matter what's contained in the POST variable nothing will break (at least not during the assignment).

Comment: sorry for being dense, but could you update your answer with how?

Answer (score 2):

That is **how you are supposed to do it**, JavaScript cannot access the POST values in another way.

Offcourse you can make it a bit more beautiful: have your php-script put the POST variables in an array, and print the array in **JSON format**. Now your javascript has the array.

Answer (score 1):

POST values are being sent to the server. Once submitted only the server can work with those values. Your example is pretty much the only option you have to "access" POST values that have been sent to the server in the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

JS has no access to POST values, it can only retrieve GET values. However, since you're using a PHP script and you're able to pass the data to JS - why not give your JS functions data in JSON format? You can use PHP's json_encode function to encode all POST values to JSON that you can use then easily in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
On second step Page 2:

Set hidden text box on page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='text1' id = 'text1' value='<?php echo $_POST['desiredDatum']; ?>' />
```

Now if you use jQuery the wirite below given code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var shameful = $('#text1').val();

});
```

if not using jQuery Then

```
var shameful = document.getElementById('text1').value;
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.